# MEAN vs LAMP api

Tags: api, mobile, ionic-framework, mean-stack, lamp

I want to start a project that would consist of a web app and a mobile app. The app is for sharing nice spot with the localization and some pictures.
I've done research, but I can't decide if I'm better to go with MEAN or with LAMP. What are your advices ?

Thanks !

PS: I also haven't decided yet if the mobile apps are going to be native or cross-platform with Ionic, so I you have some advice for this, I could be nice too !

Comment: Please don't rated negatively my question, I don't understand why, but all my questions are rated like this. I've asked technical questions and questions for advices/opinions, and they always end up with a negative rating. I don't want to be block from the forum, so please give me advice instead of negative rating. Thanks 

Comment: MEAN is suitable for non one-off projects as these projects tend to scale and becomes harder to maintain. LAMP is suitable for one-off projects (simple website, blogs, etc) as it's simple, faster and easier to setup. Hence, this question is vague as ppl don't know what kind of app you want to be build and the answers can be very opinionated (like the one by @khajaamin). A vague question usually gets downvote as ppl also assume you didn't do enough research. This kind of question is more suitable to be asked in MEAN/LAMP/Quora forums.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0):

People here get pretty tight in the panty when it comes to opinion based questions.

Best you ask this on the official [Ionic Support Forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/?utm_source=framework&utm_medium=navbar&utm_campaign=forum%20CTA) instead.

Comment: I can try, but wouldn't people be biaised on this forum ?

Answer (score 0):

I am hybrid app lover as long as it goes for maps and light operations  but it seems though there are good hybrid frameworks not 100% performing for every mobile operations like navigation and other there web view goes crazy.

better to user hybrid for small apps and for api I always support for MEAN and there are loopback like frameworks which should be your best choice. please read it and let me know if helps.

ref:
https://strongloop.com/

## khajaamin

Comment: I've read what you sent me and on loopback framework, I had never heard of these. I read that it was faster using these frameworks, but how is it faster and what are they other advantages / disadvantages ?

Thanks !